# Log4j2 encoding issue

Tags: elasticsearch, character-encoding, log4j

When I try to run Elasticsearch on Windows 10 as main language is English, everything works fine. But if I change the main language as Turkish, I get error messages as:

```
2018-07-26 14:42:39,485 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for IfFileName
2018-07-26 14:42:39,633 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for IfAccumulatedFileSize
2018-07-26 14:42:39,634 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for IfFileName
2018-07-26 14:42:39,637 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction for element Delete: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.findNamedNode(PluginElementVisitor.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.visit(PluginElementVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.generateParameters(PluginBuilder.java:248)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:958)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:898)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:890)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:890)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:890)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:513)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:249)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:261)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:119)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:291)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:85)

2018-07-26 14:42:39,645 main ERROR Null object returned for Delete in DefaultRolloverStrategy.
```

So it seem like a charset problem. The file is encoded as `UTF-8`, I check it with Notepad++. Elasticsearch has JVM option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. I double checked the log4j2.properties file and `IfFileName` has no space after it.

And if I change `IfFileName` as `ıfFileName` (which `ı` is a Turkish character - lower I) error becomes:

```
2018-07-26 14:54:25,819 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Ä±fFileName
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `-Duser.language=en` JVM parameter fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (it happened in the sonarqube installation for me which uses elasticsearch.) but didn't know where to add the `-Duser.language=en`. However, I found it out it is under the sonar.properties, the line where  `sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=` is located remove the # at the begining and write as `sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Duser.language=en` and save the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Log4j2, which uses [`String#toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)) without a locale parameter: in the Turkish locale `IfFileName` is lowercased as `ıffilename` (with a dotless i). I have reported this as [GH issue #1281](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1281).

Until this is fixed you can write plugin types in all lowercase (English) letters: e.g. `iffilename` instead of `IfFileName`.